# Remove multiline regex with Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to remove a line which sets an attribute `last-lrm-refresh` (typically the last line in a group of settings) where input looks e.g. like this:

```
dc-version=1.1.16-94ff4df \
cluster-infrastructure=corosync \
maintenance-mode=false \
last-lrm-refresh=1523005561
```

The following does not work. What am I doing wrong? I have Perl v5.20.2 installed.

```
perl -pe 's/ \\\n[ \t]+last-lrm-refresh=[0-9]+//smg' < in.out > out.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible it's a windows line ending? In which case you'd want to be matching `\r\n` - probably as `[\r\n]+`

Comment: @Scoots Nops, it's Unix (Debian).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading a line at a time where a line is defined as a number of character ending with newline, so `\n[ \t]` can't possibly match. You can address this problem by changing the definition of a line to be the entire file (`-0777`).

```
perl -0777pe 's/ \\\n[ \t]+last-lrm-refresh=[0-9]+//' in.txt > out.txt
```