# Remove substring with Ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to use Ruby's `sub(pattern, replacement)` for removing a line of the form `last-lrm-refresh=<value>` from a multi-line substring. Here is an example of the entire string:

```
       maintenance-mode=true \
       last-lrm-refresh=1523448810 \
       no-quorum-policy=stop
```

The following does not quite work:

```
s.sub(' \\\n[ \t]+last-lrm-refresh=[0-9]+', '')
```

When I try the same regular expression in an interactive regular expression editor (such as [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)) it works fine, so I guess the problem is about escaping characters.

What is the right form of regular expression to pass a string into `sub` to achieve the desired effect? I've tried a few "permutations" but without success so far. (I've also tried something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793266/remove-multiline-regex-with-perl) with Perl before.)

Comment: `s.sub(/ \\\n[ \t]+last-lrm-refresh=[0-9]+/, '')` - use a **regex**, not a **literal** string substitution.

Comment: `' \\\n[ \t]+last-lrm-refresh=[0-9]+'` is not a regular expression. It's a string.

Comment: I suggest closing as a typo. Can't find a good dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove *the line*, it could be easier to support if you’ll be *removing a line* instead of regexping everything:

```
input = "maintenance-mode=true
       last-lrm-refresh=1523448810
       no-quorum-policy=stop"
input.split($/).reject do |line|
  line.strip.start_with?("last-lrm-refresh=")
end.join($/)
#⇒ maintenance-mode=true
#  no-quorum-policy=stop
```

Or, even easier for Ruby 2.4+, credits to @Stefan

```
input.each_line.grep_v(/(^\s*last-lrm-refresh=)/).join
```

Comment: Or something like `input.each_line.grep_v(/last-lrm-refresh=/).join`

Comment: Thx. The thing is that `last_lrm-refresh=...` may appear in the last line, in which case I'd also like to remove the previous /\\\n/. That's why the regex-based approach came to mind.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. My code effectively removes _the whole line_.

Comment: @rookie099 just `chomp` it afterwards. The fact that the last "line" isn't a proper line should not make you jump through hoops.

Comment: @Amadan `chomp` is not needed, actually.

Comment: @rookie099 my version may actually result in a trailing newline because `each_line` preserves it. You can avoid that via: `input.split($/).grep_v(/(^\s*last-lrm-refresh=)/).join($/)` (or `"\n"` instead of `$/`)

Comment: @Stefan: ...or easier with `input.each_line.grep_v(/(^\s*last-lrm-refresh=)/).join.chomp`. :)